# Android error Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept

Tags: android

имеется код:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(APIUrl.BASE_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();

                APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

                Call<Result> call = service.userLogin(login, password);

                call.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Log.d("Статус",String.valueOf(response.code()));
                        if(response.isSuccessful()) {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            if(!response.body().getError()){
                                finish();
                                SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).userLogin(response.body().getUser());
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class));
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                             Toast toast =Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ошибка подключения к серверу. Пожалуйста, попробуйте позднее",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                             toast.show();

                            Log.d("Статус",String.valueOf(response.code()));
                            Log.d("Ошибка",response.errorBody().toString());
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Log.e("Ошибка", t.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });
```

При авторизации стала выдавать ошибку: `Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $`
Что это значит? Эта ошибка выходит из метода onFailure()

**UPD**
Postman с такими же параметрами выдает `{"error":true,"message":"Invalid email or password"}`

Comment: проверяли запись в БД?

Comment: @ДмитрийШевчук поправил вопрос

Comment: вы не поправили, вы полностью изменили вопрос. Я к андроид никакого дела не имею

Comment: Если постман выдаёт такую же ошибку то проблема не с приложением а с серверной частью. Предоставьте код серверной части

Comment: @danilshik Вы бы удалили вопрос. Поступают ответы от участников, которые не видят вашего удалённого ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ от сервера не соответствует модели, которую вы указали как тип данных возвращаемых сервисом (выложте описание интерфейсов и классов в нем), чтобы точно подтвердить.

Тут код https://stackoverflow.com/a/36002007/5892568 который включит "расслабленный" режим.

Comment: Не совсем так - ошибка говорит о том, что сама строка не соответствует спецификации json и можно попробовать проигнорировать эту проверку, включив "расслабленный" режим, как Вы говорите. А ругается он скорее всего на [BOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: @SergeMarkov ошибку не исправило